# How to open leaflet marker popup from data geojson with href

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I get `markers` and data `popups` from `geojson`.

I want to open a specific `popup` from `href`. I need you to open popup using its `ID` or another way.

I saw [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/ZkC5M/) example but I don't know how can I implement it in my code.

Here is my sample `geojson` data

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-67.9283981,10.1497326]},"properties":{"id":107,"text":"Marker 1"}}
```

and here is my code

```
$.getJSON('get_mapa_getjon.php', function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.id + '<br />' + feature.properties.text);
            }
    });
geojson.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the `geojson` layer and check for feature property like `id` in our case this way

```
geojson.eachLayer(function(feature){ //geojson is the object which have your data

    if(feature.feature.properties.id=='required-id'){ //insert the id in place of 'required-id'
        feature.openPopup(); //open popup for matching ID
    }
    //remove the below line if you have multiple features with same ID
    break;//exit loop once it opens the popup
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/6s77xfhg/)

Comment: thank you so much I tried and is working How transform it in function, am I right ?                              "function test(id){
    var id = $(this)[0].id;
    geojson.eachLayer(function(feature){
        if(feature.feature.properties.id==id){
            feature.openPopup();
        }"

Comment: I tried to call from jquery but it doesn't work, I want pass value to function, can you  help me with a example.  Thank you again

Comment: I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/6s77xfhg/). There is a button which have `onclick` function. Please have a look and tell me if it works

Comment: Thank you muzaffar apreciate your help